# Component vs. Control

Tags: winforms, controls, components

In the world of WinForms .Net controls

What is the difference between Component and Control?

- Can a Control contains any Component?
- Can a Component contains any Control?

Comment: This article may help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1dk63b.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Control has all the plumbing required to act as a window.  The ability to respond to Window messages (WndProc) and having a Handle being foremost.  Component is missing all that.  It is really rather simple, it has design time support to set properties and it can be disposed, that's all.

Components still can have a runtime representation, OpenFileDialog being the best example.  But that is actually a dialog built into Windows, not Windows Forms.

Comment: And it appears components have no `Load` event. So how do you perform initialization that needs to occur after the form that hold the component has loaded???

Comment: In general, a component doesn't know what form it is sited on at runtime.  So would not care about the load state of the form either and the constructor is good enough to do all required initialization.  Click the Ask Question button to explain your requirements.

Comment: My component definitely cares, as all the event handlers are null when the constructor runs. You can see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332643/determining-when-the-owner-of-a-component-has-loaded). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A Component is just a representation of an object/sub API. eg. ImageList is a component which is invisible and is just an API into a set of images. The fact you can drag and drop them onto forms is just sugar in the designer.

A Control is intended to be visible/interactable/nestable.

Comment: There is other part of question as well.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment, the Component and Control can be seen in the Object browser as being from different object hierarchies. A Component cannot be added within a Control, as the Controls collection only accepts objects with base type of Control.

A Component cannot contain Controls.

Answer (score 1):

A **component** is basically a class (it can be a dll, Activex Object).

- It does not have User Interface capabilities that's why you cannot see a visual representation.
- It is portable and not specific to any language.

While on the other hand **control** is component which provides User Interface capabilities.

- Since control has UI, you can see its visual representation.
- It is language specific and not portable.