# Are controls components?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Just terminology question. Some articles mention that things like Button, Panel, SplitPanel, etc. are controls. Some called components. Is Both correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Component Vs Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672730/component-vs-control)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component vs. Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672730/component-vs-control)

Answer (score 7):

I think you're talking not about Visual Studio, but .NET.

[System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) class signature:

```
public class Control : Component, IDropTarget, ISynchronizeInvoke, IWin32Window, IBindableComponent, IComponent, IDisposable
```

[System.ComponentModel.Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) class signature:

```
public class Component : MarshalByRefObject, IComponent, IDisposable
```

Thus, a Control is a Component.

Answer (score 6):

The `Control` is a **Visual Component**. every control is a component but not all the components are controls.

Comment: Also, components go into `Component Tray` and controls go on `UI Design Surface`. (Sticking to Windows Forms Context)

Answer (score 1):

Controls are one kind of component.

Class libraries are also considered components.

A component is a set of (normally related) classes distributed in one package (i.e. a dll).

Answer (score 1):

A control *is a* component; but a component is *not necessarily* a control.

Answer (score 0):

Well,visually speaking usually components are a subset of controls. Just check the tools tab and you will see one section called components.

They are controls that have not a direct visual representation at the form like an ErrorProvider, an ImageList, a Timer, etc ...

[image]